# When products are being updated using a script function (by a cron), is there any way to identify or trace the function that editted the script?

Tags: wordpress, cron, product, custom-wordpress-pages, cron-task

the goal of this question is to find anything, by which it would be possible to identify an ID or anything, by which it would be possible to track a function (preferably by its name / slug) that was editting or updating prices for all products (lets say by a factor of 1,25), that were imported to the store automatically by cron).

Each time the fuction updates a product, it could for example store someplace a value that this given function editted the product for the last time.

So far I have searched for some options, the ones that I found were the following:

1) get_the_author_meta("display_name");
2) get_the_modified_author();

However, none of these options are useful, or I have not managed to make them echo anything at all.

**The expected results are:**

1) To find a way how to track a function updating posts (products) by leaving a trace or ID, that would document that given function that performed the last edit.

2) To find a way how to identify the newly created traces per each post and be able to use it with other fuctions.

**The ultimate goal is:** To make sure that when a function goes through lets say 4000 products and the fuction does not finish due to some external cause - it does not make another pass from the beginning, but changes only the products it did not change yet.

If the process does not finish, the funtion is being restarted by a cron from the beginning (until it finihes) - which at the moment causes problems - because the already updated product prices by factor 1,25 are being updated over again by the same factor.

Would anyone have any ideas?

Code:

```
private function set_custom_price($product) {
    if (!$product->exists()) {
        return false;
    }

    $product_price = $product->get_regular_price();

    if (($product_price > 0) && ($product_price < 401)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + ($product_price*(0.5)))/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 400) && ($product_price < 801)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 120)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 800) && ($product_price < 1101)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 150)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 1100) && ($product_price < 1601)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 200)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 1600) && ($product_price < 2001)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 220)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 2000) && ($product_price < 5001)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + ($product_price*(0.15)))/10) *10-1);
    }

    $product->save();
    // HERE SOME CODE NEEDED TO REGISTER TRACE??
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a code sample so that we are able to look and help achieve the needed result. However, generally, if you already have a specific function updating products, this should be pretty straight forward. You could save `prefix_last_changed` meta to any edited product after it is changed and check for this meta key on each update to avoid repetition.

Comment: Thank you. Would you have any sample code for the saving process? :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use something like this:

```
$product_id = $product->ID;
$last_changed = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_product_last_change', true );
$last_changed_timestamp = strtotime($last_changed);
$current_datetime = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()));

// Check if change date is in last 24 hours ( you can change that to what ever you want, last week, last month..etc )
if($last_changed_timestamp > $current_datetime - 86400){

    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_product_last_change', date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()) );
    // Do the changes here
}
```